# API Call via PHP Loop Results in Duplicate Values

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP script which takes an array as input and iterates over it, passing each value to an API.  While it returns results, it does so twice for the first entry in the array.  I can't seem to figure out why no matter how many times I echo or var_dump the results.  Here is the array.

```
$subjects = array('effectiveShelvingOrder%3E=%22QA*%22%20and%20effectiveShelvingOrder%3C%22QB*%22', 
'effectiveShelvingOrder%3E=%22NA*%22%20and%20effectiveShelvingOrder%3C%22NX*%22');
```

Below is the code which iterates over the array.  In theory with each iteration of the loop, cURL should receive a single entry from the $subjects array and return a set of results.  However whenever I try to do something, for example `var_dump($items)`, from within the loop I get an array with two sets of results corresponding to the first entry in the $subjects array.  This doesn't happen when I try the API call in Postman or use var_dump outside of the array.  Am I misunderstanding something about how loops and/or var_dump works in this case.

```
$items = array();

foreach($subjects as $value) {
echo $value . nl2br("\n");
    //Query FOLIO to get items in a particular call number range
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://okapi-skidmore.folio.ebsco.com/item-storage/items?query=(' . $value .')%20and%20(metadata.createdDate%3E=%222021-09-01%22)&limit=50',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'X-Okapi-Tenant:'.$tenant. '',
        'x-okapi-token:'.$token. ''
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);
    
    array_push($items, json_decode($response, true)); 

   }
```

Comment: We can see that you've put a lot of effort into your question, but I would recommend that you read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and focus on the "minimal" part. You have added a lot of text that doesn't add any value to the question. It rather detracts from it, making it much harder to understand your actual issue (hard to see the forest for all the trees). Present what you're trying to do (without all the background), example data, expected result and what currently happens. We'll ask if we have any questions.

Comment: during your test try to only push in $items when the statusCode from your curl query is 200.

Comment: After posting the question I realized there may be a totally different way to do this better.  I put the cURL code in a function and then made it a method of an object.  Then I called the object from within the loop, which seems to produce the expected result.